# Using custom code, how can I fetch data from the WordPress plugin repo?

Tags: plugins, api

In the WordPress repo, on the main page for every plugin, it displays the date of the plugin's last update ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RqVR.jpg)).  From my own WordPress site, is it possible to fetch this data with custom PHP and/or JavaScript code?  I would like to fetch this information for each plugin that is installed on my site, then display it on the Dashboard-->Plugins page.

Perhaps there is some sort of API available which makes this data accessible for all plugins in the WordPress repo?

If possible, I might also want to fetch other data related to the plugin, e.g. 'WordPress version' and 'Tested up to.'

Comment: See [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress.org_API#Plugins) (and check the examples linked from there).

Comment: @SallyCJ Bringo, that's exactly what I wanted--thanks.  Am I allowed to mark this as the solution?  Or do you need to formally add it as an answer first?

Comment: I've just posted an answer.. :)

Comment: hello and good day I'm currently working on a parser to fetch metadata on the newest plugins in wordpress. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61679425/parse-and-process-html-in-php-fetching-wordpress-plugin-metadata-with-a-scraper
your approach is much simple - many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Perhaps there is some sort of API available

**Yes, there is**, and you can check it out [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress.org_API#Plugins).

There are examples linked from that Codex page, and you might want to use version 1.2 (`GET` requests only) or 1.1 of the API where these versions both have the response format in JSON.

*And actually, there's also [`plugins_api()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugins_api/) which make things easy for you; however, you'd need to manually load the file where the function is defined (`wp-admin/includes/plugin-install.php`).*

#### Example using `plugins_api()`

```php
// You may comment this out IF you're sure the function exists.
require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin-install.php';

$args = [
    'slug' => 'woocommerce',
];

$data = plugins_api( 'plugin_information', $args );
//var_dump( $data );

if ( $data && ! is_wp_error( $data ) ) {
    echo 'Latest version: ' . $data->version;
}
```

#### Example with manual HTTP requests

```php
$args = [
    'slug' => 'woocommerce',
];

$url = 'http://api.wordpress.org/plugins/info/1.2/';
$url = add_query_arg( [
    'action'  => 'plugin_information', // first param for plugins_api()
    'request' => $args,                // second param for plugins_api()
], $url );

$res = wp_remote_get( $url );
if ( ! is_wp_error( $res ) ) {
    $data = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $res ) );
    //var_dump( $data );
    echo 'Latest version: ' . $data->version;
}
```

Either way, if you want to *exclude certain fields* like reviews and read-me sections like "description" and "installation", you can use the `fields` argument like so:

```php
$args = [
    'slug' => 'woocommerce',
    'fields' => [
        'sections' => false, // excludes all readme sections
        'reviews'  => false, // excludes all reviews
    ],
];
```

Comment: OK thanks for that. In the `plugins_api()` example you gave, you `require()`d plugin-install.php, with the caveat, `// You may comment this out IF you're sure the function exists.`  Why wouldn't the function exist?  If I was using a version of WordPress before 2.7?

Comment: Hi. Sorry, what I meant with that is, cases such as a plugin may have already included the file on the page.

Comment: OK got it--thanks very much!

Comment: hello and good day I'm currently working on a parser to fetch metadata on the newest plugins in wordpress. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61679425/parse-and-process-html-in-php-fetching-wordpress-plugin-metadata-with-a-scraper
your approach is much simple - many thanks

Comment: hi there - once again me: @Sally CJ : what if i want to get all the meta data of the plugin ?° - as it is shown in the avove mentioned thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61679425/parse-and-process-html-in-php-fetching-wordpress-plugin-metadata-with-a-scraper .- guess that this must be possible too,. °!?

Comment: @zero You can do `var_dump( $data );` to see the available information in `$data`. And you should also check the [`plugins_api()` reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugins_api/).

Comment: hello dear Sally CJ - many many thanks for the hints: awesome! really overwhelming the plugins api. You hit the point. Many many thanks for all you did!!! keep up the great work here. You rock - cf 
cf  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51990613/getting-a-list-of-all-plugins